# How to provide application.properties file to spring boot docker image as input

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I have spring boot docker image. I provided all arguments(environment variables) in application.properties file. How to provide this file while running the application through docker image as input.

Please help me.

Comment: is it general application.properties or you have profie sepecific application.properties?if its not profile specific, it will be picked by default. No need to pass anything

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. How and From which location it chooses?

Comment: resources/application.properties

Comment: Sorry. Here I am running the application through docker image.

Comment: It takes it from the classpath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use docker volumes and start your spring boot application within the docker image like

```
java -jar /path/to/volume/yourapp.jar --spring.config.location=file:/path/to/volume/application.properties
```

The `application.properties` is then externalized to the folder the volume is associated to.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. You provided the exact solution what I required.

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark it as accepted answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: What would the docker run command look like? I'm confused why you have "yourapp.jar" on the java command line . Shouldn't the property file be passed in the docker run command  as a -e with the volume mount.  I'm trying to do the same thing for an external file in my post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884167/docker-windows-10-mounting-a-volume-failing

Comment: @haju The command in my answer is part of the docker file. I agree that the path to the jar file is confusing because it is usually part of the docker image and not located in the volume. As for the properties file, you could also use an environment variable to specify the relative path starting from the volume. In my case, it's just fixed, I expect the file to be exactly in the root of the volume and it must be called "application.properties".